# Solve this system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the system of equations: $$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{y+1}{\sqrt{x}}=\dfrac{x+y}{x}\\[0.1in]
2\sqrt{y}+\dfrac{x-2}{\sqrt{y}}=\dfrac{2y+x}{y}\end{cases}$$

---

From a comment by the OP (with minor spelling corrections):

I tried , but I can't find the root . Because when I solve this , I have : $8(x+2y)=\frac{4(x+y)^2}{x} -\frac{(x+2y)^2}{y}$. I think we can $x=f(y)$ from $ (*)$

Comment: I tried , but i can't find the root . Because when i slove this , i have : $8(x+2y)=\frac{4(x+y)^2}{x} -\frac{(x+2y)^2}{y}.$ I think we can $x=f(y)$ from $ (*)$

Comment: That gives you a cubic, which implies that there are up to 3 solutions for the value of $\frac{x}{y}$, which when you plug back into the equation gives you the solutions. However, nothing seems nice here.

Comment: The comment by the OP should be included in the question as it adds context. I don't think this should be closed for lack of context.

Answer (score 1):

My CAS and Wolfram|Alpha agree that the only real solution is $x \approx 0.68163$ and $y \approx 2.43917$.

I do not think you are going to have much luck solving this by hand as it will likely reduce to a sixth degree polynomial.

Comment: This link may be of use: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2sqrt%28%28sqrt%28x%29+%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%2Bx%29%29%2F%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%29%29+%2B+%28x-2%29%2Fsqrt%28%28sqrt%28x%29+%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%2Bx%29%29%2F%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%29%29+%3D+%282%28%28sqrt%28x%29+%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%2Bx%29%29%2F%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%29%29+%2B+x%29%2F%28%28sqrt%28x%29+%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%2Bx%29%29%2F%282-2+sqrt%28x%29%29%29